# Why child process is waiting while using fork and pipes for stdin from parent's output?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, low-level

I understood how fork and pipes work but i have a doubt regarding the flow of the child and parent process.Since we are using fork the order of execution of parent and child process is undefined but why child process is waiting for stdin from parent process.What happens if child process executes first? it must print empty in console? but it is not happening can i know why?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
int main () {
int fds[2]; pid_t pid;
/* File descriptors for the two ends of the pipe are placed in fds. */
pipe (fds);
/* Fork a child process. */ 
pid = fork ();
if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {
/* Child proces -. Close the write end of the file descriptor. */
close (fds[1]);
/* Connect the read end of the pipe to standard input. */
dup2 (fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
/* Replace the child process with the “rev” program. */
execlp("rev", "rev", 0); }

else {
/* This is the parent process. */
    FILE* stream;
/* Close the read end of the file descriptor. */
    close (fds[0]);
/* Convert the write file descriptor to a FILE object */
    stream = fdopen (fds[1], "w");
    fprintf (stream, ",ereh ot ereht morF\n");
    fprintf (stream, ",ereht ot ereh dna\n");
    fprintf (stream, ".erehwyreve era sgniht ynnuf\n"); 
    fprintf (stream, "ssueS .rD - \n");
    fflush (stream);
    close (fds[1]);
/* Wait for the child process to finish. */
    waitpid (pid, NULL, 0);
}
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: child and parent will execute in parallel, so child will block on read until a little bit later, when parent has had a chance to execute for a bit and put some data into the pipe...

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom:  *one one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three kinds of returns  1) <0 means an error occurred 2) == 0 means the child process is executing  3) >0 means the parent process is executing.  The code needs to check for all three kinds of returns

Comment: regarding: `execlp("rev", "rev", 0); }`  If this statement returns, it means an error occurred. so the statement should be followed by: `perror( "execlp failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `pipe (fds);`  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `/* Connect the read end of the pipe to standard input. */
  dup2 (fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);`  This will have no effect on the execution of the program: `rev`

Comment: regarding: `execlp("rev", "rev", 0); }`  The last parameter should be a pointer, not an integer.  suggest `execlp("rev", "rev", NULL); }`

Comment: regarding: `fflush (stream);`  Since the last call to `fprintf()` format string ends in '\n', There is no need for this statement

Comment: You might want to make your code much simpler by learning about the functions: `popen()` and `pclose()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child.

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

In this case, the child needs to close `fds[1]` after duplicating it.  Because it is still open, `rev` will never receive EOF because there is a process (the `rev` child process) that could, in theory, write to the input.

You should use `fclose(stream)` instead of `close(fds[1])` because the output is buffered and `fclose()` knows to flush the buffers, but `close()` hasn't got a clue.  However, by using `fflush(stream)` before the misguided `close()`, you do avoid problems.

That leads to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fds[2];
    pid_t pid;

    pipe(fds);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == (pid_t)0)
    {
        close(fds[1]);
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        execlp("rev", "rev", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *stream;
        close(fds[0]);
        stream = fdopen(fds[1], "w");
        fprintf(stream, ",ereh ot ereht morF\n");
        fprintf(stream, ",ereht ot ereh dna\n");
        fprintf(stream, ".erehwyreve era sgniht ynnuf\n");
        fprintf(stream, "ssueS .rD - \n");
        fclose(stream);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the output:

```
From there to here,
and here to there,
funny things are everywhere.
 - Dr. Seuss
```

Comment: In your code-snippet you are closing fds[1] twice, I assume the second close is supposed to close fds[0] after the dup, right?